# prove or disprove that:$a^2+b^2+c^2\leq \frac{27}{4}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I tried to solve the below problem, I spend more than 5h just for prove it but without any result , this is the best attempt I did ,just I need to show that   $a^2+b^2+c^2\leq \frac{27}{4}$

> if $a,b,c>0$ and $2abc+3(ab+ac+bc)=27$.
> prove that;$16(a^2+b^2+c^2)+8abc\geq 135$

**My attempt:**

$2abc+3(ab+ac+bc)=27$$\Leftrightarrow$$10abc+15(ab+ac+bc)=135$

so$135\leq 16(a^2+b^2+c^2)+8abc$$\Leftrightarrow$  $10abc+15(ab+ac+bc)\leq 16(a^2+b^2+c^2)+8abc$$\Leftrightarrow$$2abc+15(ab+ac+bc)\leq 16(a^2+b^2+c^2)$.

We know this;$15(ab+bc+ac)\leq 15\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}=15(a^2+b^2+c^2)$(*)(schwartz inequality).

and

$2abc\leq 2\sqrt{(\frac{(ab+ac+bc)}{3})^3}\leq 2\sqrt{\frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^3}{27}}$.

Let's show that :
$2\sqrt{\frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^3}{27}}\leq a^2+b^2+c^2$

$2\sqrt{\frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^3}{27}}\leq a^2+b^2+c^2$$\Leftrightarrow$$ \frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^3}{27}\leq \frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2}{4}$$\Leftrightarrow$$ \frac{4(a^2+b^2+c^2)^3}{4.27}-\frac{27(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2}{4.27}\leq 0$(**)

If (**) is true then we will have $ 2abc\leq a^2+b^2+c^2$ and that's what we need for complet the proof .

Put$ f(x)=4x^3-27x^2$ ,the only positive solution of this function is$\frac{27}{4}$,and after the variation tableau of this function We can see that $f(x)\leq 0$ for$ x\leq \frac{27}{4}$.

then  $ \frac{4(a^2+b^2+c^2)^3}{4.27}-\frac{27(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2}{4.27}\leq 0$,so  $ 2abc\leq a^2+b^2+c^2$

$\color{blue}{\textrm{note that $ :a^2+b^2+c^2\leq \frac{27}{4}$}}$

So finally; after (*) and (**) we can say that :$ 2abc+15(ab+ac+bc)\leq 16(a^2+b^2+c^2)$,and this complet the proof .

the problem is that:i can't show why  this $\color{blue}{\textrm{ $ :a^2+b^2+c^2\leq \frac{27}{4}$}}$ is true

So my question is that :can you prove or disprove this:$\color{blue}{\textrm{ $ :a^2+b^2+c^2\leq \frac{27}{4}$}}$ ?.

Note that:( i dont want any answers for the general problem,just i need to develop my attempt if that is possible)

Comment: Did you mean 
"Let's show that $\sqrt{\frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^3}{27}}\leq a^2+b^2+c^2$" instead of "Let's show that $2\sqrt{\frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^3}{27}}\leq a^2+b^2+c^2$"

Comment: @DevanshBhardwaj the quoted inequality with $\geq135$ at the top of the question is true, but the asker's intermediate workings are not correct

Comment: @Anas, you should fix your question. You clearly did something wrong because your (derived) assertion has a simple counterexample (as exemplified by Ekesh Kumar's post below) but the original proposition is consistent with the counterexample. Which means you obviously did something wrong somewhere, and what you want help with cannot be shown as it is not true. So please either rephrase the question to asking for help with proving the original proposition or retract it entirely. It is unanswerable, especially with your last line saying you don't want help with the general problem. Thank you.

Comment: @Anas, did you simply reverse the sign of the inequality by mistake?

Comment: @Deepak frankly i did not understand what you mean, but the countrexample  is for $a^2+b^2+c^2 \leq 27/4$ not for thr original question

Comment: @Anas Let me try to be clearer .Your title asks for help in proving $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \leq \frac{27}4$. You have also mentioned this a few times in your post. The given conditions are that $a,b,c>0$ and $2abc+3(ab+ac+bc)=27$.  Do you still think that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \leq \frac{27}4$ is a correct inequality given those conditions in the question?

Comment: @Anas In other words, do you believe that $(a,b,c>0) \cap (2abc+3(ab+ac+bc)=27) \implies a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \leq \frac{27}4$?

Comment: @Deepak no , and ling  showed why$ a^2+b^+c^2\geq  \frac{27}{4}$

Comment: @Deepak  please look at my own answer

Comment: @Anas Exactly! Which is why your main current post, with a title appearing right at the top, is completely misleading! That's the first thing people see when clicking on the link or searching for it, which is why I strongly think you should change it. I would suggest just asking for a proof of the *original* correct proposition in your question instead of your incorrect derived inequality. In other words just say: if $a,b,c>0$ and $2abc+3(ab+ac+bc)=27$, prove that $16(a^2+b^2+c^2)+8abc\geq 135$ without any references to this wrong inequality at all.

Comment: @Anas I just feel incorrect statements don't belong in the main post, let alone in the title itself. Unless you are asking specifically and explicitly in the title for a counterexample or disproof.

Comment: @Deepak  ,Yes I understand you ,thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First by
$$a^2+b^2\geq 2ab,\,b^2+c^2\geq 2bc,\,c^2+a^2\geq 2ca$$
we get
$$a^2+b^2+c^2\geq ab+bc+ca.$$
Then combining with $2abc+3(ab+bc+ca)=27$ yields
$$\begin{aligned}
16(a^2+b^2+c^2)+8abc&=16(a^2+b^2+c^2)+4(27-3(ab+bc+ca))\\
&= 16(a^2+b^2+c^2)-12(ab+bc+ca)+108\\
&\geq 4(a^2+b^2+c^2)+108.
\end{aligned}$$
Hence it suffices to prove $a^2+b^2+c^2\geq\frac{27}{4}$. Asuume by contradiction that $a^2+b^2+c^2<\frac{27}{4}$, and note that $a^2+b^2+c^2\geq 3\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}$, we have
$$\begin{aligned}2abc+3(ab+bc+ca)&\leq 2\left(\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{3}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}+3(a^2+b^2+c^2)\\
&<2\left(\frac{9}{4}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}+3\times\frac{27}{4}\\
&=2\times\frac{27}{8}+3\times\frac{27}{4}=27\end{aligned}$$
contradict with $2abc+3(ab+bc+ca)=27$. Hence $a^2+b^2+c^2\geq\frac{27}{4}$. Then we are done.

(PS1: it is easy to check that " = " holds iff $(a,b,c)=(\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2})$.

PS2: We can also get $a^2+b^2+c^2\geq\frac{27}{4}$ by solving the inequality $2\left(\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{3}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}+3(a^2+b^2+c^2)\geq 27$.)

Comment: nice proof......

Answer (score 7):

$(a, b, c) = (1, 1, 3)$ is a counterexample.

Comment: @DevanshBhardwaj It satisfies the condition.

Comment: It is a counterexample to the (erroneous) thing that OP wants help with, but not the actual problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the inequalities
$$
\left(\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}3\right)^{1/2}\overset{\substack{\text{Cauchy}\\\text{Schwarz}\\\downarrow\\[3pt]\\}}{\ge}\overbrace{\left(\frac{ab+bc+ca}3\right)^{1/2}}^u\overset{\substack{\text{AM-GM}\\\downarrow\\[3pt]\\}}{\ge}(abc)^{1/3}\tag1
$$
The given condition implies
$$
\overbrace{\ \ \ 2abc\ \ \ }^{\le\,2u^3}+\overbrace{3(ab+bc+ca)}^{9u^2}=27\implies u\ge\frac32\tag2
$$

---

**Solution to the general problem**

> Therefore, $$ \begin{align} \hspace{-1cm}16(a^2+b^2+c^2)+8abc &=4\cdot27+16(a^2+b^2+c^2)-12(ab+ac+bc)\tag{3a}\\ &\ge108+4(a^2+b^2+c^2)\tag{3b}\\ &\ge108+12u^2\tag{3c}\\ &\ge135\tag{3d} \end{align} $$ Explanation:  
>  $\text{(3a)}$: $2abc+3(ab+bc+ca)=27$  
>  $\text{(3b)}$: Cauchy-Schwarz says $a^2+b^2+c^2\ge ab+bc+ca$  
>  $\text{(3c)}$: $(1)$ says $a^2+b^2+c^2\ge3u^2$  
>  $\text{(3d)}$: $(2)$ says $u\ge\frac32$

---

**Solution to the requested problem**
$$
\begin{align}
a^2+b^2+c^2
&\ge3u^2\tag{4a}\\
&\ge\frac{27}4\tag{4b}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(4a)}$: apply $(1)$
$\text{(4b)}$: apply $(2)$

That is, the requested inequality is reversed.

Answer (score 0):

Let us call $2abc+3(ab+bc+ac)-27=\phi(a,b,c)$
Let us use the method of [Lagrangian Multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier).
\begin{align}\mathcal{L(a,b,c.\lambda)}=16(a^2+b^2+c^2)+8abc+\lambda[2abc+3(ab+bc+ca)-27]\end{align}
\begin{align}\nabla \mathcal{L(a,b,c,\lambda)}=0=\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 32a+(8+2\lambda)bc+3\lambda(b+c)=0 \\
32b+(8+2\lambda)ca+3\lambda(c+a)=0 \\
32c+(8+2\lambda)ab+3\lambda(a+b)=0\\
 2abc+3(ab+bc+ac)-27=0\\
\end{array}
\right.\end{align}
The [solutions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=32a+%2B+%288%2B2l%29bc+%2B+3l%28b%2Bc%29+%3D+0%2C+32b+%2B+%288%2B2l%29ca+%2B+3l%28c%2Ba%29+%3D+0%2C+32c+%2B+%288%2B2l%29ab+%2B+3l%28a%2Bb%29+%3D+0%2C+2abc%2B3%28ab+%2B+bc+%2B+ca%29+-+27+%3D+0) to these equations are :
\begin{align}(a,b,c)=(-3,-3,\frac{-9}{4}),(\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2})(-2.60769,-2.60769,-3.22566)\end{align}
(as the inequality and the constraint in symmetric, order of $a,b,c$ does not matter)

Now our additional constraints $a\ge 0,b\ge 0, c\ge 0$, the equation $16(a^2+b^2+c^2)+8abc=r(a,b,c)$ :

Suppose $a=0, b\neq 0, c\neq 0$ from equations 2 and 3, $\frac{32b}{3c}=\frac{32c}{3b}$ unless b and c are zero, and thus $b=\pm c$; however, $b=-c$ leads to imaginary b and c, and so $b=c=3$
\begin{align}r(0,3,3)=288\end{align}

(The constraint equation would not be satisfied for two or more of $a,b,c$ being zero)

So by the theorem of Lagrangian Multipliers, $(\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2})$ is a local minimum of $r(a,b,c)$ in the set S where:
\begin{align}S=\{(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{R}^3|\phi(a,b,c)=0(a\ge0,b\ge0,c\ge0)\}\end{align}
**EDIT**
Just to make it complete, we have:
\begin{align}r(\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2})=135\end{align}

Comment: Would using wolfram alpha for solving the linear equations be considered unacceptable as an answer?

Comment: This looks correct, but it would be nice to explain that $(0,3,3)$ came from solving the two variable Lagrangian.

Comment: @robjohn sir edited,  but I wanted to know what in the answer still attracts the downvote, and what could be improved more.

Comment: I have gotten many mysterious downvotes on what I thought were good answers. The issue might be the advanced level of Lagrange multipliers considering the elementary level of some of the other answers. It could be something unrelated to the content of your answer. People who give these kind of downvotes rarely give a reason. (+1) for the alternative answer, and thanks for editing your answer.